# Getting Integers into Byte Arrays according to bizarre protocols

Tags: java, arrays, minecraft, bukkit

I am constructing a byte array which contains data about a block which has changed.

I have integers `x`, `y`, `z` and `blockID`, `blockMeta`:

```
Bit mask       Width    Meaning 
00 00 00 0F    4 bits   Block metadata
00 00 FF F0    12 bits  Block ID
00 FF 00 00    8 bits   Y co-ordinate
0F 00 00 00    4 bits   Z co-ordinate, relative to chunk so can fit
F0 00 00 00    4 bits   X co-ordinate, relative to chunk so can fit
```

How would I get the integers into the array?
I can safely assume that the integer will 'fit' if that is an issue.

This is what I got so far:

```
byte[] data = new byte[blocks.length * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    int j = i * 4;
    int blockX = blocks[i].getBlockX() - (chunk.getX() * 16);
    int blockY = blocks[i].getBlockY();
    int blockZ = blocks[i].getBlockZ() - (chunk.getZ() * 16);
    int blockID = material.getId();
    int blockMeta = 0;
    // data[j] = // Help!
    // data[j + 1] = //Help!

    // data[j + 2] = //Help!
    // data[j + 3] = //Help!
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code to do this? If so, please post it here.

Comment: The bit mask is your friend - twiddle.

Comment: Despite me trying for several hours I don't think I've written anything worthwile @hofan41

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
byte[] finalMessage = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt( (blockX << 28) | (blockZ << 24) | (blockY << 16) | (blockID << 4) | blockMeta ).array();
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be reverse so j goes to j+3 etc?

Comment: That depends on the endian-ness of your bitmask. Does it read msb -> lsb or lsb -> msb?

Comment: I updated my answer to use ByteBuffer since all you are doing with this bitmask is compacting a few integers into one integer (i.e. 4 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    int[] data = new int[blocks.length];
for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i ++) {
    int blockX = blocks[i].getBlockX() << 28;
    int blockY = blocks[i].getBlockY() << 16;
    int blockZ = blocks[i].getBlockZ() << 24;
    int blockID = material.getId() << 4;
    int blockMeta = 0;
    int result = blockX | blockY | blockZ | blockID | blockMeta;
    data[i] = result;
}
```

If you really need as bytes:

```
    byte[] data = new byte[blocks.length*4];
for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i ++) {

    byte byte0 = material.getId() << 4 | blockMeta;
    byte byte1 = blockMeta >> 4;
    byte byte2 = blocks[i].getBlockY();
    byte byte3 = blocks[i].getBlockZ() | (blocks[i].getBlockX() >> 4);
    data[4*i] = byte0;
    data[4*i + 1] = byte1;
    data[4*i + 2] = byte2;
    data[4*i + 3] = byte3;
}
```

Comment: Cheers - I think I have to reverse it as this is the wrong endian for me I believe.

Comment: I'm getting incompatible types:
Required: byte
found: int

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] finalMessage = ByteBuffer.allocate(20).putInt(x).putInt(y).putInt(z).putInt(blockID).putInt(blockMeta).array();
```

Comment: Seems pretty wasteful to create 5 `ByteBuffer`s. Why not just do it all in a single `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: Why does that conform to the protocol?

Comment: according to a protocol, I updated the question - sorry.